# htaccess rewrite php to html, no post method?

Tags: php, html, forms, .htaccess, http-post

I use this htaccess to rewrite php extensions to .html.
I have a valid form which should be posting to an url, but I can't get the post data, I think this has something to do with the htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mypath/

# Rewrite to SEF URL's
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.html index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Does someone has a solution to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you must use a non-greedy regular expression. Replace `.*` with `.*?`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)\.html index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4 [QSA,L]
```

and the others appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Feeling a bit stupid I couldn't find that for myself.

Comment: @FIA2008 No need to feel bad. It took me many, many years to learn, what I know now. And I'm still learning. That's the reason, why I answer questions here on SO. :-)